# Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on resizable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request which basically gets some HTML and puts it inside a `<DIV>` tag.

However, if I then call something after this happens (like clicking a button) and try using div.append to that same DIV, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on resizable prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

This is basically some snippets of my code:

```
if (formreq) {
  $.ajax({                                      
      url: './json/admin/getHTML.php',                       
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      data: { FORMSEQ : formreq } ,                      
      dataType: 'json',                   
      success: function(result)          
      {
      var HTML = result["HTML"];
        $('#blankform').append(HTML);
      } 

    });
```

Then if I use something like:

```
$("#div_" + selectedItem).resizable('option', 'disabled',true);
```

Which the selector is a valid element on the HTML that was called via Ajax, I get the above error.

Any idea's? - Thanks

Comment: When (and where) are you initializing the resizable widget?

Comment: Dynamically added elements are not automatically initialized in the currently used plugin. You will have to do it manually again.

Comment: Its being initialized after the Ajax request has been called, inside a .click event on another button 'outside' the #blankform DIV

Comment: You need to make sure you don't run the above `option` code before the user clicks on the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize resizable with the `disabled` option specified. It's in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#method-disable).

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({ disabled: true });
```

Comment: Thats brilliant, thank you Andy. I understand the error message now you have given me the solution :)  Thanks